# Texture Video Progress Depends on Render Starting Frame

Tags: animation, video, frame-rate

I'm struggling to understand how Blender processes video as a texture and can't find anyone else online who has the same problem as me.

To give some background: I have recorded the screen of my iPhone for approximately 1 minute and imported this video as a plane in Blender as part of a 3D app preview with real gameplay footage. I have overlaid animation in Blender on top of the footage and this doesn't seem to sync with the footage. When I play a preview in the Material view the background video plays at a different speed to when it is rendered. The transformation is not linear but seems to depend on how much movement is happening in the video texture i.e. if two frames are identical then only one is shown.

This isn't an unsurmountable problem however if I rchange the starting frame then the resulting render will be different which for obvious reasons is not ideal. Could anyone help me with this problem? I'm very happy to provide further details or examples however I'm not entirely sure what to provide. I have included some basic details below:

Video texture file type: .MOV
[image]

Comment: Search here for codec issues. Sounds like B / P frames.